# Laravel: @can throws error on query builder?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code in my blade file:

```
@if(Auth::user()->isLeader())
 <input type='hidden' name='leader' value='{{ Auth::id() }}'>
@endif
```

This works.

I want to shorten the code by using [can](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-blade-templates) so I created a guard in the AuthServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
     $this->registerPolicies();

     Gate::define('isLeader', function ($user) {
        return $user->isLeader();
     });
}
```

and changed the blade file to:

```
@can('isLeader')
   <input type='hidden' name='leader' value='{{ Auth::id() }}'>
@cannot
```

If I now open the blade file I get the following error:

> "Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isLeader()"

[image]

Why is that happening?

Edit: That is my `isLeader` function:

```
public function isLeader()
{
  $leader = static::where('id','=',$this->id)->leader();
  if($leader->count() == 0){
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure but are you missing `$this->registerPolicies();` statement?

Comment: Is there a user logged in at this point? Maybe `$user->isLeader()` is failing because `$user` isn't a model object

Comment: @Jeff yes a user is logged in. I don't understand why he is calling the query builder.

Comment: @ab_ab yes I forgot to add it here, but it was there in my original code. So this is not causing the error. I will edit this part.

Comment: User model still has a isLeader? Laravel Models have a __call() function that passes everything that is not a function to the Builder. You could also dd the $user in the Gate function to make sure you are getting the expected user object.

Comment: Where is the User Model? It has the Authorizable trait?